# distribution of $X=(e^Y-1)^{1/\theta}$ where Y is exponential distributed

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $Y \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ what's the NAME of the distribution of X such that
$$X \equiv (e^Y -1)^{1/\theta}$$ where $\theta$ is a positive constant.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that the random variable X obeys the CDF

$F_X(x)=1-\frac{1}{(1+x^{\theta})^\lambda}$ , $x\in[0,\infty)$

which can subsequently be classified as a [Pareto type IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Pareto_types_I%E2%80%93IV) with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$.